# Laravel 5.2 how to write this where clause in view?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to if check user has give his vote for certain post. And I want to use this where clause in view somehow. Is there are any possibility ?

```
$used = Vote::where('post_id', $id)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();
```

Can I write this somehow in Blade using `@if` ?

**EDT**

When I do this:

`User model`:

```
public function vote()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
}

public function voted($postId)
{
    return $this->vote()->where('post_id', $postId)->count() > 0;
}
```

`PostsController`:

```
return view('index', compact('posts'))->with('user', Auth::user());
```

And in my view:

```
    @if ($user->voted($postId))
          // some button
    @endif
```

I get: `Undefined variable: postId`

This is my route:

`Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index');`

Comment: In what file do you get the `Undefined variable` error? In View or i Model?

Comment: @Kocik Index.blade.php

Comment: And in this line: `@if ($user->voted($postId))` - where do you get `$postId`  from? I need some context.

Comment: And in index.php I've included posts.blade.php from layouts folder

Comment: @Kocik I think it's from user model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use queries directly in the view. How about defining a method on the `User` model for this purpose. The solution below assumes you have a relation to the user votes defined on you `User` model as well.

So you should have this in your `User` model:

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\Votes::class);
}

public function voted($postId)
{
    return $this->votes()->where('post_id', $postId)->count() > 0;
}
```

Then in your route closure or controller action you can return:

```
return view('yourview')->with('user', Auth::user());
```

Or just use [View Sharing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) so you don't have to pass the authenticated user to the view every time:

```
view()->share('user', Auth::user());
```

And then your Blade view file you can then just write this:

```
@if ($user->voted($postId))
    <!-- Do your stuff -->
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if ($user->voted($postId)) // in this place you need $postId defined
      // some button
@endif
```

To do that you need either throw $postId to the viewbag

```
return view('yourview')
    ->with('user', Auth::user())
    ->with('postId', $currentPostId); //change $currentPostId to your
                                      //variable, probably like: $post->id
```

Or if you are iterating over all posts, you need to get it form a post model:

```
@for($posts as $post)
    //...   
    @if ($user->voted($post->id))
        //...
    @endif
    //...
@endfor
```

Hope it answers your question ;)

Comment: Can u please add me to chat ? I'm getting frustrated with this.

Comment: If you still have problems, please send a link to pastebin with your controller and template files, plus whole error message that you are getting.

Comment: So , you have your loop: `@foreach($posts as $p)` so in the loop you have `$p` variable representing the post. So you need to use the same variable in the if statement: `@if ($user->voted($p->id))`.

Comment: I'm getting this: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasVotedFor()

Comment: But in my Post.php I have the method hasVotedFor

Comment: In my index.blade.php I have this:  `@include('layouts.posts')`

Comment: Can you check that is true: `Auth::check()`?

Comment: Also, make sure that in `config/auth.php` you have right user model specified. And that it's full qualified class name of that model!